# Unable to inherit css

Tags: django-models, inheritance, django-views, django-templates

[Unable to inherit css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds5eo.png)

I am facing a problem. Why there are red lines under { symbol and % **symbol in style tag in basic.html**? How to fix this problem?

**This is basic.html(parent template)**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-PJsj/BTMqILvmcej7ulplguok8ag4xFTPryRq8xevL7eBYSmpXKcbNVuy+P0RMgq" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}  {% endblock %}</title>
    
        <style> {% block css %} { % endblock % } </style>
    

    </head>
    <body>
    {% load static %}
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  {% block body %}  {% endblock %} 
</body>
```

**This is about.html** (inheritance from basic.html)

```
{% extends 'shop/basic.html' %}

{% block title %} Titile of About {% endblock %}

{% block body %}  {% endblock %}
```

**This is index.html**

```
{% extends 'shop/basic.html' %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-PJsj/BTMqILvmcej7ulplguok8ag4xFTPryRq8xevL7eBYSmpXKcbNVuy+P0RMgq" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>مرحبًا بالعالم!</title>
    
      {% block css%}
      .container{
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
      {%endblock%}

  </head>
<body>
  
  <!--        carousel indicators starts from here-->
<!--        carousel indicators starts from here-->
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
        card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
        card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
        card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

I am facing a problem. Why there are red lines under { symbol and % **symbol in style tag in basic.html**? How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PJsj/BTMqILvmcej7ulplguok8ag4xFTPryRq8xevL7eBYSmpXKcbNVuy+P0RMgq"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>

    <style>{% block css %}{% endblock %}</style>

</head>
<body>
{% load static %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

{% block body %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have posted the code. You may check now

Comment: The {% load static %} tag seems to be used for template rendering. To use Django template tags like this, you need to ensure that your HTML file is part of a Django project and is being rendered by Django's template engine.

Additionally, it seems that there is a missing {% extends %} tag at the beginning of the file, indicating that this template extends a base template. Make sure to include this line if it's meant to be part of a template hierarchy.